# Error en formula de volatilidad con pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Buenas: Tengo estas dos lineas de codigo donde quiero calcular los retornos de una accion y la volatilidad de la accion.

```
GFG['Log_Ret'] = np.log(GFG['Close'] / GFG['Close'].shift(1))

GFG['Volatility'] = pd.rolling_std(GFG['Log_Ret'], window=252) * np.sqrt(252)
```

Cuando trato de ver la volatilidad, me da este error:
module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_std'

Que puedo hacer?... Veo el paquete de pandas y esa es la funcion

Comment: ¿Que versión de pandas usas? Has consultado esto: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.std.html. Se me hace que `rolling_std` esta deprecado en versiones más nuevas de pandas. Saludos.

Comment: Uso la mas nueva, la 0.23.0

Comment: Tal como comenta Patricio en Pandas 0.18 las funciones `rolling_*` pasaron a estar marcadas como "deprecated" y ser sustituidas por los métodos correspondientes.  Si no me equivoco debería ser  `GFG['Log_Ret'].rolling(window=252).std()`

Comment: Gracias, muy agradecido con ustedes